# Finding smallest and largest population and the average

Tags: java, average, delimiter

I've been working on getting this program to work. I'm having a little trouble getting the program to read the files I have created, `census2000` and `census2010`. These contain the 50 states and their population in 2000 and 2010. I believe that the rest of my program is correct. I was told to use methods to find the smallest population, largest population and the average. Here is two lines from the 2000 file:

Alabama     4447100

Alaska      626932

Here is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String state = "";
        int population = 0;
        int p = 0, s = 0, pop = 0, stat = 0, populate = 0, sum = 0;
        File f = new File("census2000.txt");
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(f);
        infile.useDelimiter("[\t|,|\n|\r]+");
        while (infile.hasNext()) {
            checksmall(p, s);
            checklargest(pop, stat);
            checkAverage(populate, sum);
            population = infile.nextInt();
            state = infile.next("/t");
            System.out.println(state + "has" + population + "people");
        }

        System.out.println(state + "has smallest population of" + population);
        prw.close();
    }

    public static boolean checksmall(int p, int s) {
        boolean returnValue;
        if (p < s) {
            returnValue = true;
        } else {
            returnValue = false;
        }
        return (returnValue);
    }

    public static boolean checklargest(int pop, int stat) {
        boolean returnVal;
        if (pop > stat) {
            returnVal = true;
        } else {
            returnVal = false;
        }
        return (returnVal);
    }

    public static int checkAverage(int populate, int sum) {
        int retVal;
        retVal = populate + sum;
        return (retVal);
    }
      }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include the files you are trying to read so that we can see the format.

Comment: The check* methods are called before you read the data and you've only got two variables for all the data in your files( so maybe your going to call check* in the loop ).  Presuming you just want to read the output of the file scan, do the scanner next* tests match the data format of the files?

Comment: When I do this I get the error input mismatch exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
state = infile.next("/t");
```

I think what you're trying to do is skip a tab in the file and read the state? You could do that by reading in the line and then splitting the line using `\t` as the delimiter.

```
String line;
while (infile.hasNextLine()){
    line = infile.nextLine();
    String data[] = line.split("\\s+");
    state = data[0];
    population = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
}
```

edit: also as the other answer points out, you're attempting to perform functions on the file's data before it's read.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException comes up after I do this

Comment: That means that the first value in your file line is not an int (or that the file is not tab delimited). You should definitely post an example line from your file.

Comment: @CBH are they all wriiten in one line or on different line.

Comment: the problem is that state is before population. You're getting a numberformatexception because you're trying to turn the state into an int. I'll edit the answer

Comment: They are all on separate lines

Comment: I just switched the state and population and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Then above code should work. @MementoMori +1 However its better to use `\\s+` instead of `\t` to use whitespaces as delims.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be calling checksmall, checklargest and checkAverage after/while the file is loaded.

Comment: I get this java.util.InputMismatchException